# How can I check if a property has been set using Swift reflection?

Tags: swift, reflection

Some of my models have optional properties. I'm trying to write a method that can evaluate if they've been set.

Below is an attempt, but I can't figure out how to determine a nil value from an `Any` object [edit: (the `child` variable is of type `Any`)]. It doesn't compile.

```
func allPropertiesHaveValues(obj: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
    for child in mirror.children {
       let value = child.value
       if let optionalValue = value as? AnyObject? { //Does not compile
          if optionalValue == nil {
             return false 
          }
       }
    }
    return true
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I forgot to clarify that the `child` value in the above example is always of type `Any`. The `Any` type is difficult in that it cannot be compared to `nil` and a cast to `AnyObject` always fails. I've tried to illustrate it in the playground below.

```
var anyArray = [Any]();

var optionalStringWithValue: String? = "foo";
anyArray.append(optionalStringWithValue);

var nilOptional: String?
anyArray.append(nilOptional)

print(anyArray[0]);   // "Optional("foo")\n"
print(anyArray[1]);   // "nil\n"

if let optionalString = anyArray[0] as? AnyObject {
    //will always fail
    print("success")
}

//if anyArray[1] == nil {  //  will not compile

//}
```

Comment: You said that you can't figure out how to determine a nil value from an `Any` object. If the object has the type `Any` it cannot be nil. If you want your object to be nil or have a value you should declare it as optional : `Any?`

Comment: You can assign a nil optional value to an Any variable. `var a = [Any](); var b: String?; a.append(b); print(a[0]);` ---> String? = nil

Comment: Ok like that. I only thought about assigning `nil` to an `Any` declared object. And that you can't

Comment: Now I understand better. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used @ebluehands technique of reflecting the `Any` value to modify the original function. It cycles through the properties with an initial mirror, then reflects each one individually using `displayStyle` to determine if the property is optional.

```
func allPropertiesHaveValues(obj: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
    for child in mirror.children {
        let value: Any = child.value
        let subMirror = Mirror(reflecting: value)
        if subMirror.displayStyle == .Optional {
            if subMirror.children.count == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This is undocumented API so I would really warn against using this in production.

Answer (score 4):

**Obsolete:**

You can simply check if the optional value is nil or not :

```
func allPropertiesHaveValues(obj: AnyObject) -> Bool {
   let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
   for child in mirror.children {
     //child.value being an optional
     if child.value == nil {
       return false
     }
    }
   return true
}
```

---

**Edit:**

To check if an `Any` object is optional and contains a value or not using reflection :

```
let optionalString : String? = "optional string"
let any : Any = optionalString

//First you will need to create a mirror of the any object
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting : any)

//Then you can check the display style to see if it's an optional
if mirror.displayStyle == .Optional {
    //If it is, check the count of its children to see if there is a value or not
    if mirror.children.count == 0 {
        print("I don't have a value")
    }
    else {
        print("I have a value")
    }
}
```

---

Here is a playground example (based on yours):

```
var anyArray = [Any]()

var optionalStringWithValue: String? = "foo"
anyArray.append(optionalStringWithValue)

var nilOptional: String?
anyArray.append(nilOptional)

let string = "string not optional"
anyArray.append(string)

print(anyArray[0])   // "Optional("foo")\n"
print(anyArray[1])   // "nil\n"
print(anyArray[2])   // "string not optional\n"

let mirrorOptionalWithValue = Mirror(reflecting: anyArray[0])

if mirrorOptionalWithValue.displayStyle == .Optional
    && mirrorOptionalWithValue.children.count == 1 {
    print("Is an optional and contains a value")
}

let mirrorOptionalWithoutValue = Mirror(reflecting: anyArray[1])

if mirrorOptionalWithoutValue.displayStyle == .Optional &&
    mirrorOptionalWithoutValue.children.count == 0 {
    print("Is an optional but is nil")
}

let mirrorNotAnOptional = Mirror(reflecting: anyArray[2])

if mirrorNotAnOptional.displayStyle != .Optional {
    print("Is not an optional")
}
```

Comment: A Mirror's child.value is of type `Any`, which cannot compared to nil. I don't think your example will compile.

Comment: I wasn't sure what child.value had as type. It's why I added the comment. Can you update your question with a simple definition of `children` ?

Comment: Wow thanks. This is great. I used your technique to modify the original function and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is create a extension.

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    func checkIfAllRequiredMembersAreSet() -> Bool {
        let attributes = self.entity.attributesByName

        for (attribute, value) in attributes {

            if value.attributeValueClassName != nil {
                let v: AnyObject? = self.valueForKey(attribute)
                if !value.optional && v != nil {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40927739/1202867), I recommend using `if case Optional<Any>.some(_)`.

I did something recently to make sure I have at least one optional set. Here's an example to make sure all are set. You can paste into playgrounds:

```
import Foundation

struct SomeError: Error {
    let code: Int?
    let message: String?
    let errorDescription: String?

    var allValuesSet: Bool {
        for aChild in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
            if case Optional<Any>.some(_) = aChild.value {
                continue
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}

let errorTest = SomeError(code: nil, message: "failed", errorDescription: nil)
let errorTest2 = SomeError(code: -1, message: "failed", errorDescription: "missing information")

print("is valid: \(errorTest.allValuesSet)") //is valid: false
print("is valid: \(errorTest2.allValuesSet)") //is valid: true
```